# python subprocess.Popen hangs on alternating stdout and stderr writes

Tags: python, subprocess

I've reproduced the problem with a script that writes to x bytes to stdout and y bytes to stderr.
running it using `subprocess.Popen` hangs.

```
x = 100000
y = 100000
p = subprocess.Popen(f'./a.py {x} {y}', shell=True , stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdout.read()
#Hangs here
```

#a.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
out=int(sys.argv[1])
err = int(sys.argv[2])

for i in range(out):
    print('a', end='')
    if i < err:
        print('a', end='', file=sys.stderr)
```

try to increase x and y if the problem does not reproduced.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen(['python', './a.py', str(x), str(y)], ...)`

Comment: which OS are you using?
can you try `stdout, stderr = p.communicate()` and then `print(stdout, stderr)`?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters  I'm using WSL, but it did happen also in Ubuntu.
I forgot to add `p.stdout.read()` at the original post (which seems to hang), 
but p.communicate() doe's not hang, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the problem. But if I'm right, when I used subprocess and needed it on the same stdout, each time I used `print()` I've attached:

```py
print("Your subprocess printing..", flush=True)
```